# Archiving an Asana Project using the API

Tags: asana, asana-api

How can I archive a project using the api?

The api documentation for [projects](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects) shows that projects have an 'archived' attribute, but when I try to [update](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects#update) it, I get a message that it's read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to write to this endpoint in the Asana API.

Comment: Can you please consider this a feature request then?

Comment: Yes, I'll pass it along to the API team.